# google maps Autocomplete country restrictions IE8 error

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I have an issue where when I try to restrict autocomplete to just US, it fails on IE8.
Unable to find any help so far, so I appreciate anything. The error and success functions are executed depending on whether or not the user allows us to track their locations.
On IE9 it won't work at all if I don't allow, on IE8 it fails regardless. Updated with latest code (DNRY...)

```
   function setupPlacesAutocomplete() {
       if (navigator.geolocation != undefined)
           navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(successFunctionAC, errorFunctionAC);
       else
           errorFunctionAC();
   }
   //refactor this method
   function getFudgedBounds(lat, lng, fudge) {
       return new google.maps.LatLngBounds(new google.maps.LatLng(lat - fudge, lng - fudge), new google.maps.LatLng(lat + fudge, lng + fudge));
   }
   function successFunctionAC(position) {
       var defaultBounds = getFudgedBounds(position.coords.latitude, position.coords.longitude, .2);
       var options = {
           bounds: defaultBounds,
           componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' }
       };
       setAutoComplete(options);
   }
   function errorFunctionAC() {
       var defaultBounds = getFudgedBounds(parseFloat(geoip_latitude()), parseFloat(geoip_longitude()), .2);
       var options = {
           bounds: defaultBounds,
           componentRestrictions: { country: 'us' }
       };
       setAutoComplete(options);
   }
   function setAutoComplete(options) {
       var input1 = document.getElementById('StartSearchTerm');
       var autocomplete1 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input1, options);
       var input2 = document.getElementById('EndSearchTerm');
       var autocomplete2 = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input2, options);
       $('.pac-container').css('z-index', 9999);
   }
```